# How to align an a tag vertically?

Tags: html, css

I see this pattern often.

Can I use it to center align a HTML tag?

```
.pattern {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

How does it work exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question of what the positioning does:
- when you set an element to fixed with a top and left of 50%, that sets the element to display with the top left corner at that position within the viewport. So therefore the top left corner is centered vertically and horizontally. But only the top left corner is centered within the viewport, so what the remaining styling does is center the element relative to that point.  This is usually done by translating the element by 50% of its height and 50% of its width, so that now the center of the element is in the centered position.

The following demonstrates this:

```
  .centered{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);  
  }
```

To show in pictures (please excuse the dodgy quality of the images)
[image]

Comment: I should add that you should try to avoid using this method of centering content too much. Transforming elements are performed AFTER rendering the text, so inner content and text may get blurry on some devices/browsers when this trick is used too much. If your browser limitations permit, try to use flexboxes instead.

Comment: This is a good solution for starters.  How does flex handle centering?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}
.pattern {
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="pattern" href="#">Demo Text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain how this code works?  Trial and error is good but I'd like to understand the reasoning.

Comment: Whenever you have used `transform` and `top` property, it identifies its parent `height` and `position`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{margin:0; padding: 0;}
.wrapper{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">Demo Text</a>
</div>
```

I would like to recommend to use `flex`.

If you want to know about `flex`, try to go here https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv?q=flex&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: why do you have class pattern when you add no styles to it?

Comment: @rebeccakan You don't need to care about that. It's not important.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex for center aligning an element both horizontally and vertically.

Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/5sLef3pz/

```
<div class="flexbox-container">
    <div class="flex-item">flex item centered</div>
</div>
```

Its related CSS

```
.flexbox-container {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```